# Is there no need to free() a heap variable allocated and returned from a thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, heap-memory

As far as I know, `malloc()`(or any heap allocation function) and `free()` must be paired. I thought it is the same in the multi-threaded programs. But it looks like I should not `free()` a heap variable that was allocated at another thread.

When I run the code below (in wsl ubuntu environment),

```c
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void* thread_main(void* arg) {
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < *((int*)arg); i++) {
        printf("thread running... %d\n", i);
    }

    char* msg = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
    msg = "thread end\n";

    return (void*)msg;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t thread_id;
    int thread_arg = 5;
    void* thread_return;

    pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, thread_main, (void*)&thread_arg);
    pthread_join(thread_id, &thread_return);

    printf("thread returned message : %s", (char*)thread_return);

    free(thread_return);  // if I comment out this line, the program succeeds.
    return 0;
}
```

I get an std output of

```
thread running... 0
thread running... 1
thread running... 2
thread running... 3
thread running... 4
thread returned message : thread end
munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
```

However, if I comment out `free(thread_return);` part, the program succeeds and does not produce the aborting error dump message.

So, is there no need to free the heap variable created from another thread? Or even more, is it wrong to free the heap variable if it was created from another thread?

Comment: `msg = "thread end\n";` you just leaked the memory allocated on the prior line, `msg = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);`. The return address in `msg` is no longer heap; it's a read-only literal string, and invoking `free()` against it invokes  *undefined behavior*.

Comment: `msg = "thread end\n"` drops the pointer returned by `malloc()`, so the call of `free()` in `main()` is passed a pointer that was not returned by `malloc()`.   Instead of `msg = "thread end\n"`, use `strcpy(msg, "thread end\n")`.

Comment: To confirm what @WhozCraig just said, run your program with valgrind . In fact, I suggest you use valgrind every time you have memory allocation issues.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks I didn't know that line was to blame. I was wrongly blaming the innocent free(); I should call it. I would have picked your comment as an answer if it wasn't a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char* msg = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
msg = "thread end\n";
```

The second line here overwrites the pointer allocated by `malloc()` with a pointer to a constant string, causing the memory that was originally allocated to be leaked. The value returned by this thread points to that constant string, not the memory allocated by `malloc()`; attempting to `free()` that value will fail, because it was not allocated by `malloc()`.

Use `strncpy()` to write a string to the memory allocated by `malloc()`. Once you've done that, you can (and should) deallocate the resulting memory with `free()` in the main thread.

Comment: Alternatively, return the constant string and don't free it.

Answer (score 0):

**In Short**

Always free allocated memory in the same logical unit that allocated it.

**Reasoning**

If you free memory that was allocated on another thread, or even say a dynamically allocated buffer you received as a parameter to your function, which you decide to free - you can cause a lot of problems.

Future use of this variable can cause your program to crash since it tried getting to unallocated memory.

It's really a best practice to do as i wrote in the summary, especially when writing code for bigger projects with multiple developers - since you can't always know what will happen in the future of the dynamically allocated buffer.

**The Crash**

Addressing your crash, it isn't caused by you trying to free memory allocated on another thread - it simply happens since by using the line:

```
msg = "thread end\n";
```

right after allocating the memory and assigning it to msg, you lost your pointer to the allocated memory. Now when freeing "msg" you are trying to free a variable allocated on the stack.

Comment: Interesting, if not benign advice, but it has nothing to do with the crash of OP's program.

Comment: It doesn't address his crash, since he asked about freeing variables created on the heap and how you should handle them. Ill refrence the crash too

Comment: Not my down-tick, but the crash, and method for avoiding it which the OP feels unsure about, is the very reason for the question in the first place. If you address one, you should point out what was wrong in the first place.

Comment: You're right. Though I'd prefer not suggesting a specific way to solve it since now that the OP knows the logic that  caused the error he should think of his own solution to the problem.